# Calling Public variable from userform

Tags: vba, excel

In a userform, I have this at the top:

```
Public DelMonth As Variant
```

The value of DelMonth is read from a ComboBox, and I can call it from different subroutines within that userform just fine. But when I call it from a separate module, it doesn't read it. It doesn't even throw an error. If I do a `MsgBox DelMonth`, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You need to use `userformname.DelMonth` from any routine outside the form.

Answer (score 3):

A form is an *object*; a public field in an object module belongs to an *instance* of that object. UserForms are little more than class modules with a default instance (i.e. a `VB_PredeclaredId = True` attribute) and a designer.

If you're using the form's *default instance* (a rather bad idea), then you can do this:

```
MsgBox UserForm1.DelMonth
```

Note that storing state in global objects is bug-prone, and *will* end up causing issues.

If you're treating the form like the full-fledged class it is, then you'll have something like this:

```
With New UserForm1
    .Show
    MsgBox .DelMonth
End With
```

Note that the field being `Public` means *anyone, anywhere* can go and *write* to it. What you mean is for the *form* to determine its value, and for the *caller* to be able to **read** that value. You do this by *encapsulating* the field with a `Property Get` member - start by making the field `Private`:

```
Option Explicit
Private DelMonth As Variant ' wouldn't Integer or Long be more appropriate?

Public Property Get DeliveryMonth() As Long
    DeliveryMonth = DelMonth
End Property
```

Now the callers don't get to see the private `DelMonth`, and all they can do with `DeliveryMonth` is call the `Get` accessor, which doesn't let them tamper with the encapsulated value.

---

> *It doesn't even throw an error.*

That's worrying. You're allowing VBA to happily compile typos and otherwise illegal code. Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of *every* module. Always.

Comment: I'm trying to call DelMonth from the userform in a SaveAs dialog box. And that dialog box is closing the userform. Is that why it's not able to grab the variable?

Comment: You're doing it backwards. A form's purpose is to collect/display data, not to process it. A form doesn't *do* any work. If you've unloaded the default instance, the global state is destroyed, yes. Please do things properly, avoid global state, and have forms that do a form's job. Thank yourself later.

Comment: I'm not following. I'm setting the DelMonth variable from a userform ComboxBox. From there, in a module, I need to call that variable in a dialog box. How am I doing it backwards?

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood. So the module is retrieving the value after the form has closed, correct? If the form is `Unload`ed, or X'd-out, then the object is destroyed and the state is lost. You need to handle the `QueryClose` event to prevent that, and remove any `Unload Me` you might have in that form's code-behind. See [UserForm best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5351/user-forms/19036/best-practices#t=201708221549543791435) on Documentation.SO (quick while it's still up! SO is sunsetting documentation)

Comment: Technically, yes. I have the SaveAs box set to open before it's `Unload`ed, but it seems like the dialog box forces the userform to close automatically.

Comment: The userform should already be closed when the calling code consumes its state... In any case your question doesn't include nearly enough code to reproduce the issue.